# How to change the button text EDIT to UPDATE?

Tags: angularjs

Here i use this code to enable and disalbe text box on clicking on edit button.
but here what i want is on click of EDIT button the text of the button should change to UPDATE

```
    **CODE**
    <input type="text" input-disabled="editableInput" />
    <button ng-click="editableInput = !editableInput">EDIT</button>

     app.controller("myController", function(){
     $scope.editableInput = false;
     });

    app.directive("inputDisabled", function(){
    return function(scope, element, attrs){
    scope.$watch(attrs.inputDisabled, function(val){
    if(val)
     element.removeAttr("disabled");
    else
     element.attr("disabled", "disabled");
      });
     }
    });
```

I tried as much i can, some one help me out in this.

Comment: Maybe this will help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646264/changing-text-on-button-while-saving-using-angularjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```html
<button ng-click="editableInput = !editableInput">
    <span ng-show="editableInput">UPDATE</span>
    <span ng-show="!editableInput">EDIT</span>
</button>
```